# Ingress controller fails to post config on IPv6 cluster

Tags: ipv6, kong

I installed Kong 3.2 version using latest helm chart(2.19.0) successfully in Kubernetes IPV6 enabled cluster. But my application’s health endpoint is not accessible via Kong.

Below is the output of curl command:

```
curl http://[ipv6Address]:31221/health
```

> {“message”:“ no Route matched with those values”}

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: python-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /health
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: python-ui-service
            port:
              number: 6000
```

Version - Kubernetes-1.23.7, Helm Chart-2.19.0, Kong-3.2, Ingress Controller-2.9

I am unable to find the issue.